# Guice injection leaking into other tests

Tags: junit, dependency-injection, mockito, guice, guice-3

I use Guice to instantiate a `VocabularyAPI` object for one of my unit tests `unitTest1()`. However, for another test (`unitTest2()`), I simply use mockito's `@Mock` annotation to mock an instance of the same class - `VocabularyAPI`.

I noticed that when I only run `unitTest2()` - mockito's mock setting for my `VocabularyAPI` is configured correctly. However, when I run the entire test suite (both `unitTest1()` and `unitTest2()`), both the tests are instantiated with the settings from the injector.

How can I limit the scope of the injected object to only inside the test that it is being injected? I want to be able to use the injected object in `unitTest1()` and mocked object for `unitTest2()`.

Comment: could you please provide your test code? Its hard to imagine what you are doing without ...

Answer (score 0):

Any problems in using local variables?

In `unitTest1()`:

```
VocabularyAPI vocabularyAPI = // inject (I'm not familiar with Guice)
```

In `unitTest2()`:

```
VocabularyAPI vocabularyAPI = Mockito.mock(VocabularyAPI.class);
```